# Trying to draw image from pixel array on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas, computer-vision

I have a pixel-array of 256 values that looks something like this:

`[-7.440151952041672e-45, -3.549412689007182e-44, -1.6725845544560632e-43, -7.785321621854041e-43, -3.579496378208359e-42, -1.6256392941914181e-41, ...]`

What I am trying to achieve is, to draw this pixel array image onto the canvas. The reason why I need this, is because I will need recalculate the pixel array based on a convolution value to redraw the image with a specific filter over it.

I am currently trying to draw it using this:

```
function generate_image() {
    // create an offscreen canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas_id");
  canvas.style.cssText = 'width: 400px; height: 400px; z-index: 1;';
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

  var images = generate_image_array_data();

  // This is the pixel array of the image
  var image = images[2];

  var palette = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 160, 120);

  palette.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(image));

  ctx.putImageData(palette, 0, 0);
}
```

Using the above code nothing happens on the canvas. I am fairly certain I am doing something wrong, but I am not exactly sure what. If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to create an ImageData object of javascript using the array of pixel values I have, but the Image that gets generated with that function has value 0 in all occurrences I have checked and I am not sure why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log you shown can not be the one of an Uint8ClampedArray.
Clamped Uint8 values can't be negative, nor floats.

These are thus either 32 bits float values, or 64 bits float ones.

Once you determine which it is, you can convert it to clamped Uint8 values by doing

```
const data = new Uint8ClampedArray( original_data.buffer );
```

if `original_data` is already a TypedArray.

In case it is not, but rather a *normal* Array, you'd have to first rebuild a TypedArray from the values in that Array and then do the same conversion.

Assuming 64 bits float values:

```
const data = new Uint8ClampedArray( new Float64Array( images[ 2 ] ).buffer );
const palette = new ImageData( data, 160, 120 );
```

```js
generate_image();

function generate_image() {
  // create an offscreen canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas_id");
  canvas.style.cssText = 'width: 400px; height: 400px; z-index: 1;';
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

  var images = generate_image_array_data();

  // This is the pixel array of the image
  var image = images[2];

  var data = new Uint8ClampedArray( new Float64Array( image ).buffer );
  var palette = new ImageData(data, 3,4);
  ctx.putImageData(palette, 0, 0);
  
  ctx.imageSmootingEnabled = false;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function generate_image_array_data() {
  return [, , [-7.440151952041672e-45, -3.549412689007182e-44, -1.6725845544560632e-43, -7.785321621854041e-43, -3.579496378208359e-42, -1.6256392941914181e-41 ] ];
}
```

*PS: Don't call getImageData if you don't need the pixels on the canvas, prefer ctx.createImageData(width, height) or even new ImageData(width, height), which will both avoid your canvas bitmap buffer be (slowly) moved from the GPU to the CPU for nothing*

Comment: The values from the array are Float64 values, yes, that is correct. I managed to copy the code you have written (Many thanks as this has helped understand some topics) and managed to create the ImageData object using the initial pixel array. However, the result is not something I was expecting as this results in an image of rainbow of colored pixels which is not the desired result. I believe one of the underlying issues is the initial image array not being of bigger dimensions (256x256).

Comment: I did create a 3px x 4px ImageData based on what you gave from the log (which was obviously truncated. You'd need to create a 160 x 120 one if that's what your data represents. Also, remove the part after `ctx.putImageData(palette, 0, 0);`, I used this only to scale that 3x4px ImageData to something we could see in the snippet. Finally, you might want to set your canvas's `width` and `height` properties to this ImageData's size, to avoid white space around.